# Why doesn't java.util.List implement Serializable?

Tags: java, list, serialization, inheritance, collections

Why is it that `java.util.List` does not implement `Serializable` while subclasses like `LinkedList`, `Arraylist` do?  Does not it seem to be against inheritance principles?  For example if we want to send a Linkedlist over a network, we have to write:

```
new ObjectOutputStream(some inputStream).writeObject(some LinkedList);
```

So far so good, but while reading the object on the other side we have to explicity say `LinkedList l = (LinkedList)objectInputStream.readObject();` instead of `List l = (List)objectInputStream.readObject();`.  If we were ever to change the writing functionality from `LinkedList` to say `ArrayList`, we will also have to change the reading part.  Having `List` implement `Serializable` would have solved the problem.

Comment: I don't think the second part of your statement is accurate, not that I've had the chance to try it. What kind of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`List` does not implement `Serializable` because is it not a key requirement for a list.  There is no guarantee (or need) that every possible implementation of a `List` can be serialized.

`LinkedList` and `ArrayList` choose to do so, but that is specific to their implementation.  Other `List` implementations may not be `Serializable`.

Comment: In that case the same argument can be applied to LinkedList as well that being a very basic list, it does not to be serializable as it is not a requirement of a list.

Comment: There is a difference in forcing all the implementations of a list to be serializable, and choosing that one particular implementation is serializable.

Comment: LinkedList is an implementation, to which developers choose to give the serializable property. If we follow your reasoning no class should implement two interfaces at a time...

Answer (score 12):

List is an interface and making it extend Serializable would mean that any implementation of List should be serializable.

The serializable property is not part of the List abstraction and should therefore not be required for an implementation.

Answer (score 4):

No. A LinkedList is always a List. When you deserialize the linked list, since a LinkedList is a List, you may write

```
List l = (List) objectInputStream.readObject();
```

The fact that l is in fact a LinkedList is not important. You wanted a List, and you got a List.

Comment: Are you sure ? How would the runtime understand how to deserialize the object if you cast it to a non serializable interface ?

Comment: The cast happens after the deserialization and is thus not important here -> cast to List is fine

Comment: The runtime knows how to seserialize the object because its serialized byte stream contains the name of the class of the object that has been serialized. ObjectInputStream thus creates an instance of this class and populates it with the data found in the serialized object, and then returns it to the caller. The caller knows that it was a list that was serialized, and thus casts the returned object into a List.

Answer (score 3):

Because `List` is open to be implemented by user specific subclasses as well, and implementors may not necessarily want to implement `Serializable`. Serializability does not belong to the key responsibilities of a `List` either, so there is no reason to link the two together.

Answer (score 2):

Consider hypothetical `ThreadList implements List<Thread>`, containing the list of active threads at any given point in time. The implementation transparently browses active threads and allows easy access to them - for your convenience. Should such an implementation be serializable (forgetting that `Thread` is not serializable)?

It is up to the person implementing the interface to decide, whether her implementation is safe to be serialized. `List` is too generic, as basically stating *ordered collection of items of type T`.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be based on a misunderstanding. To serialize an object, the object (or its class) has to implement `Serializable`, but you don't need to use an expression of type `Serializable` (or some subtype) to do this. It is quite intentional that the `writeObject` method has a parameter type of `Object` and not `Serializable`, as well as the return type of `readObject()`.

But even if these parameter and return types were `Serializable`, you would not need to know the specific implementation types:

```
ObjectOutputStream stream = ...;
List myList = ...;
stream.writeObject((Serializable)myList);
```

and

```
ObjectInputStream stream = ...;
List myList = (List) stream.readObject();
```

would work as well as it works now (without the Serializable cast).

ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream do not care at all about your types when invoking, they simply look at the object at hand and its class.

Answer (score 0):

If List implements/extends Serializable then you have implied the contract that all implementation classes/subclasses of List are also Serializable which is not always true. For e.g look at the guava-collections implementation of [ForwardingListMultimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/index.html). It doesn't need to be Serializable functionally and this was possible only because List is not Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it that java.util.List does not implement Serializable ...

Because not every `List` implementation in the world must be `Serializable`.

> while reading the object on the other side we have to explicity say  ...
>   instead of

```
List l = (List) objectInputStream.readObject();
```

Have you tried it? If you do, I think you'll find that it works.

Answer (score -2):

List extends Collection, and it can't implement anything because it's an interface...

Comment: presumably the OP meant that `List` should extend `Serializable` *in addition* to `Collection`, the fact that he used the word implement should be understood in context...